# Why does the multithread function not run before the timer?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am trying to use multithreading to show a loading wheel while doing some background calculations.
I try to start the multithreaded function, and then run a timer to simulate the calculations.
The problem is the thread first starts running when the timer is over, even though I am starting the thread first...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
from threading import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# Create Object
root = Tk()
  
# Set geometry
root.geometry("400x400")
flag = True
# use threading
def threading():
    t1=Thread(target=work)
    t1.start()
    time.sleep(10)
# work function
def work():
    print("sleep time start")
    image = Image.open("Static/spinner0.png")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    lab = Label(root,image=img)
    lab.pack()
    while flag:
        for i in range(8):
            image = Image.open("Static/spinner"+str(i)+".png")
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            lab['image'] = img
            time.sleep(0.2)
        #return False
    print("sleep time stop")

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        flag = False
        root.destroy()
        
# Create Button
Button(root,text="Click Me",command = threading).pack()

# Execute Tkinter
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is `time.sleep(10)` a replacement for the calculations ?

Comment: `tkinter` won't like you modifying the GUI from a different thread.

Comment: @quamrana, it actually allows it very nicely, it just has to be done correctly.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: Do you have any references for that?

Comment: not a reference, but i have applications that work with threads that are updating the GUI in different threads, but tk documentation is a mess.

Comment: Your `time.sleep(10)` blocks `tkinter` from running. Once that has finished, `tkinter` can resume.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Yes, the time.sleep(10) is a replacement for my calculations. When doing it with my actual calculations, same result

Comment: I have only been able to use threads by sending [GUI modification] commands back to the main thread through a queue.

Comment: I got it working somewhat, by running the calculations in another thread. However, I can see that my first thread is slowed down significantly by this...

Comment: Yes, your calculations should be done in a separate thread and the GUI code should be in the main thread. However, if the calculations are CPU bound, you might want to consider multiprocessing.

Comment: yes, using `time.sleep` is bad in applications run by tk, you should instead use something like the `root.after` method.

Comment: well, the proper way to do it is to run the calculations in different thread, and have your main thread update the GUI using a method similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73745376/python-tkinter-label-not-responding/73745555#73745555) instead of using `time.sleep`

Comment: @quamrana tk is only waiting for input so it has 0 CPU usage if the screen is not changing, so it's okay to use multithreading with tk for calculations.

Comment: I've got my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59327161/4834) to link to.

Comment: not blocking the main event loop and updating GUI from multiple threads are two separate problems, you can have 10 extra threads of which 9 are updating the GUI simultaneously, and 1 doing calculations, just don't interrupt the eventloop running on your main thread unless you absolutely have to, like responding to button presses.

Comment: Remove line 16  time.sleep(10). Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the answer here to avoid people digging comments for the solution.

One way to do this is to have **both** the calculations and the updating function running on extra different threads, this way the main process event loop stays uninterrupted and you get to call `time.sleep`, which is fine so long as it doesn't happen in your main thread.

A thread in python consumes below 100KB of memory (plus memory for variables in code running on it), so it's fine to have multiple threads running.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
from threading import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Create Object
root = Tk()

# Set geometry
root.geometry("400x400")
flag = True


# use threading
def threading():
    t1 = Thread(target=work)
    t1.start()
    t2 = Thread(target=time.sleep,args=(10,)) # the heavy computation function.
    t2.start()
    # control is given back to the main event loop

# work function
def work():
    print("sleep time start")
    image = Image.open("Static/spinner0.png")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    lab = Label(root,image=img)
    lab.pack()
    while flag:
        for i in range(8):
            image = Image.open("Static/spinner"+str(i)+".png")
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            lab['image'] = img
            time.sleep(0.2)
        #return False
    print("sleep time stop")


def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        flag = False
        root.destroy()


# Create Button
Button(root, text="Click Me", command=threading).pack()

# Execute Tkinter
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you shouldn't call `tkinter` stuff from other threads

Comment: @Matiiss any reason not to do so ? .. and are you sure you are correctly referring to `tkinter` not `QT` ?

Comment: not confusing anything, the reason is that it may make `tkinter`'s interpreter crash, so calling from other threads should be simply avoided, you can also somewhat refer to quamrana's comment, it's just a known thing that you shouldn't be calling `tkinter` stuff from other threads

Comment: @ Mastiss is right about the dangers of calling `tkinter` methods from other threads. For an example look [here](https://pastebin.com/wF5Fn19a). Also you missed `global flag` at the start of `on_closing`. To improve your answer look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801).